# Wishlist icon red when in wishlist

Tags: ajax, laravel, conditional-statements

[image]in laravel when item in wishlist it should show red colour heart, but when i add an item in wishlist it changes all products heart icon in red , i want product's heart red which item is in wishlist

i am returning this query and returning true

```
$productData = $select_pro->get();
// Fetch wishlist data for the logged-in user and the product IDs
$wishlistData = DB::table('wishlist')
        ->whereIn('pid', $productData->pluck('id'))
        ->where('userid', $userId)
        ->get();
$inWishlist = $wishlistData->count() > 0;
$subImagesData = DB::table('images')->whereIn('product_id', $productData-   >pluck('id'))->get();
$data = [
        'products' => $productData,
        'sub_images' => $subImagesData,
        'inwishlist' => $inWishlist,
    ];

return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

here i am putting condition for change colour in my blade file

```
var inwishlist=response.data.inwishlist;
cardHtml += '<a href="#" id="addtowishlist" class="addtowishlist" data-productid="' + productId + '">';
cardHtml += '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x addtowishliststyle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: ' + (inwishlist ? '#8B0000' : 'white') + '"></i>';
cardHtml += '</a>';
```

Comment: what is not working? Can you tell more about the problem

Comment: my default heart icon is white , when i add one item in wishlist all item colour change into red , while i want red colour heart in item which is in wishlist

Comment: so your $productData->pluck('id') is a list of products ?

Comment: You need to select wishlist for each products and when you loop to check if exists in wishlist

Comment: Is that a single item page or a list of items? (if it is a list you probably have duplicate `id` attributes - which is invalid, `id`s must be unique)

Comment: @EfrosIonelu i will try with loop

Comment: @brombeer it is list of items , and it is unique

Comment: If you add `<a href="#" id="addtowishlist"...` to every item the `id`s will be _not_ be unique

Comment: @brombeer i have added my database image , you can check it

Comment: `id` attributes, like `id="addtowishlist"`. Not id values from your database

Comment: @EfrosIonelu loop worked , thanks   `wishlistData.forEach(function(WishList){
          var wishlist_pid=WishList.pid;
          console.log(wishlist_pid);
          if(wishlist_pid==productId)
          {
            red
          }`

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like:

```
$wishlistData = DB::table('wishlist')
        ->select('pid')
        ->whereIn('pid', $productData->pluck('id'))
        ->where('userid', $userId)
        ->get();

$data = [
        'products' => $productData,
        'sub_images' => $subImagesData,
        'wishlistData' => $wishlistData
    ];
```

// here is the loop i think

```
var inwishlist = array_search('product.id', array_column($response.data.wishlist, 'pid'));
cardHtml += '<a href="#" id="addtowishlist" class="addtowishlist" data-productid="' + productId + '">';
cardHtml += '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x addtowishliststyle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: ' + (inwishlist ? '#8B0000' : 'white') + '"></i>';
cardHtml += '</a>';
```